# Is it possible to edit a style of an element in Firebug and have this change reflected to unminified CSS/LESS?

Tags: html, css, firebug, google-chrome-devtools

This is a feasibility question:

Using **any combination** of smart IDEs, current F12 tools (not necessarily Firebug) and possibly some 3rd party plugins or software, is it possible to **load a page with minified stylesheet**, find the element on a page using an Inspector, change its style somewhere in the tool UI and **have this change reflected back in the source code**?

My current workflow is that I create some basic CSS that I think would work, then load the page in the browser, play with the styles a bit more in F12 tools when necessary and then manually update the source codes. I wonder if some toolchain improved this workflow recently by eliminating the last manual step.

Answer (score 0):

As far as Im aware thankfully not. Whilst a tool would be useful for developers imagine the damage that could be caused on public sites by malicious users

You can use the browser and source code/css file at same time and see instant changes by refreshing page but otherwise copy and paste are required

Comment: Of course you wouldn't be able to modify source files of public sites :) I am talking about some tool / switch at the development time.

Answer (score 0):

Yep this is the kind of stuff Chrome dev tools are introducing to help development work flow.  Currently it works with SASS (not LESS) and should work with CSS too, as well as other static files.

Check out this video from [Fluent 2013](http://youtu.be/bqfoYaKCYUI)

Comment: This is probably it? http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/developing-with-sass-and-chrome-devtools/ One concern, though: it seems to work for SASS, not minified CSS (unless I missed something).

Comment: I wouldn't expect it to work with minified CSS. This tool is to help speed up the development process and typically in a development environment your CSS wouldn't be minified.

Comment: I see that as a similar problem as JavaScript + minification + source maps. If it makes sense there, it should for CSS too.

Comment: Unfortunately, the source maps V3 do not (and perhaps never will) support multi-level mappings. Now, if you have _any_ kind of CSS compiler persistently watching changes to the original sources and producing compiled CSS along with source maps, you should be good to go.